# Help designing a circuit working with PWM and polarity swapping

Tags: circuit-design, relay, pwm, polarity

Hi all I'm after some advise for a circuit I'm trying to design.

I have an existing circuit that drives two low power bulbs. This is my signal circuit and runs on 12v, has a switched negative and uses PWM to make the bulb fade in and out as it transitions between on and off.

I have two, much higher power bulbs, I would like to turn on when the lower power bulb is on. This second bulbs circuit has a switched live.

I figured I could use a relay to switch the polarity of my lower power signal circuit to drive the higher power bulbs on a higher power circuit. Problem is, due to the PWM, the relay flicks wildly on and off as the bulb fades in and out.

So I thought I could try and smooth out the PWM using some form a low pass filter. Whilst I haven't tested yet I would assume I would need a rather large capacitor as the relay coil would require quite a lot of power to keep it energized.

So my question, is there a better way to solve this problem? It would be even better if my higher power bulb could be faded in and out too but if it makes it simpler just having it turn on and off would be great.

Thanks for any advice anyone can offer. I'm a software engineer, not electrical so sadly this is like magic to me.

**edit**
Just to add a little more information

The existing circuit:

- 2x 5w 12v D.C. bulbs
- constant live
- PWM controlled transitions between states (on/off)
- non PWM controlled when in the on state.
- incandescent bulbs

Second circuit:

- 2x 21w 12v DC bulbs
- switched live
- incandescent bulbs

Desired outcome:

The first circuit to act as a signal for the second circuit, not to drive it directly. I think the extra bulbs would be too much load. The first circuit is switched ground, the second switched live so something would need to translate anyway. If the second circuit could inherit the PWM that would be great but if not thats fine.

What i tried:

Using a relay. It worked, the new bulbs were powered using the first circuit as a trigger. However due to the PWM the relay flicks on off very rapidly during the PWM phase.

I tried researching how to smooth the PWM signal and that's when i read about low pass filters. However i don't think that would be suitable to smooth out the relay trigger. So wondered if there was a better way to solve this problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: we'll need more info on your bulbs. Also, you can't use PWM to dim a relay: a relay is either on or off, and far too slow to turn off and on as fast as the PWM does.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks ill update the question with more info. On the relay point. PWM, to my understanding, is just a signal that goes from one to zero, the important information is the duration. If that's true then PWM can go through a relay, just limited to how fast the mechanical switch can switch. I switched the polarity of the two circuits with a relay and it does work, new new lights do dim, but the relay flicks on and off very quick during the PWM controlled transitions between off and on and vice versa.

Comment: you're right, but typical PWM to dim a lightbulb needs to be > 100 Hz so that you don't see flickering. And your Relay won't be happy to switch more than at maybe 4 Hz, and it will be broken only after maybe 100000 switchings. You really can't *feasibly* pass PWM through a relay.

Comment: @MarcusMüller totally agree it would kill the relay. Thats why i tried to find a way to smooth out the PWM so the relay receives a solid non PWM'd signal. Thats when it got me thinking that there must be a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: but that doesn't work at all! You can't switch a relay "half on". It's either on, or off. smoothing doesn't end in a "half-way" state.

Comment: Maybe im using the wrong term then. When i say smooth i mean during the PWM phase the relay would receive a constant on until the PWM stops. The relay would only ever be on or off based on the source signal, but i flatten/smooth the PWM'd part to a constant on. Maybe debouncing would be a better description?

Comment: but if you do that, then there's no dimming?

Comment: Correct, Which is why I’m asking if there is an alternative solution to using the relay. Even better if it gets me the dimming but if not that’s an ok compromise. I accept using a relay is not good with the PWM so hoping for alternative solutions.

Comment: I assume the 12 V bulbs are incandescent bulbs?

Comment: Yep, sorry I forget there a different types. I’ll update the question.

Comment: In order to dim lights you need the PWM's frequency to change until it reaches 0. What is the voltage and current of the old and new bulbs?

https://blog.lightbulbs-direct.com/dimming-for-dummies/

And here is the circuit:
https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/71336-make-a-simple-dimmer-switch-for-incandescent-lights/

Comment: @ste2425 is the 12 V AC or DC?

Comment: It is DC. 
CFCBazar. Thanks for the info. However that doesn’t help with using the existing circuit as a trigger for the second one.

Comment: well, if it's just DC, a simple MOSFET-based switching would probably work well.